# changing one image header and one text header at the same time

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I am working a webpage right now where I have an introductory header that is displayed at the front of the page with a textual sidebar that goes with it.

The thing is that I have several headers, due to the amount of images and info the page consists of, I want to flip through the grand stories as different people visit my page.

To do this, I have a JS-script running right now that manages to change the Image header automatically without any problems. But, since I recently decided to add some sort of description to the image, I now need to change not only the image but also the text.

It might seem easy but I assure you it is not, not for me anyway.

Here is the script and the html that is affected by it.

**Javascript**

```
(function(){
var rotator = document.getElementById('bigImage');
var imageDir = '../images/';
var delayInSeconds = 5;
var images = ['1.png', '2.jpg', '3.jpg', '4.jpg', '5.jpg', '6.jpg', '7.png'];
var num = 0;
var changeImage = function() {
var len = images.length;
bigImage.src = imageDir + images[num++];
if (num == len)
{num = 0;} 
};
setInterval(changeImage, delayInSeconds * 1000);
})();
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="image-container">       
<a href="../Html/1.html"><img src="../images/1.png" height="300"    
width="650" id="bigImage";/></a>

<div id="text">
<div id="text-box">
<p></p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: what text are we talking about

Comment: I updated it. Sorry about that

Comment: What do you want to change the text to? You seem to only be keeping track of the file name

Comment: I have a matching amount of text-boxes that I want to be changed everytime an image is changed...

Comment: @ianpgall did you see my update?

Comment: @Drucker Yeah I see that. In Javascript, you're storing all of the file names (in `var images`), but where are the "descriptions" you talk of?

Comment: @ianpgall what I mean is that the descriptions will go straight into the HTML. It wont be stored in the script. I will do all of the editing straight inside the html in other words.But do you see the Divs with id text, text-box? The description goes there. I chose to leave it blank. Don't really think it matters or am i wrong?

Answer (score 0):

somthing like this?

```
(function(){
  var rotator = document.getElementById("bigImage")
    , textBox = document.getElementById("text-box") //SELECT THE TEXT BOX
    , imageDir = "../images/"
    , delayInSeconds = 5
    , images = []
    , len = images.length
    , num = 0 //why this?
    , changeImage = function(delay){
      bigImage.src= imageDir + images[num++]
      textBox.innerhtml = "hello from image nr:"+num //SET TEXTBOX CONTENT
      if(num === len){
        num = 0 
      }
     }
}())
```